# How can I find music for my instrumentation?

Tags: instrumentation

I am hoping to play the piece [Point Blank](https://www.pauldooley.net/works/pointblank) by Paul Dooley (the large chamber ensemble version). I want to find another piece to pair with it but I am struggling to find something requiring a similar instrumentation. Outside of imslp, I have not seen any websites that allow me to sort by instrumentation.

I want to generalize the question: How can I find music for any specific instrumentation (assuming there is something to find)?

Comment: Sorry, resource requests are off topic here. But afaik there is no “under-copyright” equivalent of IMSLP; just the websites of publishers and good old Google.